# RPM spec: How to erase an RPM before one is installed

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I have an RPM called `dcca-img.rpm`
In the spec file of above RPM, in `PreReqs` we have `mysql-client` and `mysql`, as a result before dcca-img.rpm is installed both are getting installed as expected.

```
PreReq: perl, mysql-client >= 5.5.43, libmysqlclient15 >= 5.0.96, libmysqlclient_r15 >= 5.0.96, mysql >= 5.5.43
```

The problem is, because of this requirement:
If there is n existing and lower version of mysql installed in the machine, it should be erased, before the newer version is installed.

Now, in `%pre` section i can put `rpm -e 'rpm -qa | grep mysql'` but that won't solve, because by then the higher version would already have got installed, as `%pre` means before RPM dcca-img.rpm is installed not before dependencies of `dcca-img.rpm` gets installed.

How can i make sure, that mysql-5.5.43 is installed, only AFTER dcca-img.rpm is installed, (resulting in `%post` getting invoked to erase a prior version one)?

Comment: AFAIK, it is impossible to control other package installation from your spec file. Only way i can think of is have wrapper script which erases lower-versioned rpm.s before installing your rpm (and the dependencies).

Comment: That's really unfortunate

Comment: I would be happy to be proved wrong :)